# What are pros and cons of colocating type declarations and use of types compared to splitting them up in different files?

Tags: typescript

Here type declarations and and use of types is colocated in the same file:

**index.ts**

```
import Connection from '../../Connection';
import { BaseRequest, IBaseRequestBody } from '../BaseRequest';

export interface GetArcIdRequestBody extends IBaseRequestBody {
    cmd: 'otii_get_device_id';
    data: {
        device_name: string;
    }
}

export type GetArcIdServerResponse = {
    cmd: 'otii_get_device_id';
    data: {
        device_id: string;
    }
};

type GetArcIdResponse = string;

export class GetArcIdRequest extends BaseRequest {
    constructor(
        arcName: string, 
        transactionId: string, 
        connection: Connection, 
        maxTime: number
    ) {
        super(transactionId, connection, maxTime);
        this.requestBody = {
            type: 'request',
            cmd: 'otii_get_device_id',
            data: { device_name: arcName }
        }
    }

    async run(): Promise<GetArcIdResponse> {
        let serverResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.push(
                this.requestBody, 
                this.transactionId, 
                this.maxTime, 
                resolve, 
                reject
            );
        }) as GetArcIdServerResponse;

        return serverResponse['data']['device_id'];
    }
}
```

Here is the same code, split up into two files:

**index.d.ts**

```
import { IBaseRequestBody } from '../BaseRequest';

export type GetArcIdResponse = string;

export interface GetArcIdRequestBody extends IBaseRequestBody {
    cmd: 'otii_get_device_id';
    data: {
        device_name: string;
    }
}

export type GetArcIdServerResponse = {
    cmd: 'otii_get_device_id';
    data: {
        device_id: string;
    }
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import Connection from '../../Connection';
import { BaseRequest } from '../BaseRequest';
import { GetArcIdServerResponse , GetArcIdResponse } from './index.d';

export class GetArcIdRequest extends BaseRequest {
    constructor(
        arcName: string, 
        transactionId: string, 
        connection: Connection, 
        maxTime: number
    ) {
        super(transactionId, connection, maxTime);
        this.requestBody = {
            type: 'request',
            cmd: 'otii_get_device_id',
            data: { device_name: arcName }
        }
    }

    async run(): Promise<GetArcIdResponse> {
        let serverResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.push(
                this.requestBody, 
                this.transactionId, 
                this.maxTime, 
                resolve, 
                reject
            );
        }) as GetArcIdServerResponse;

        return serverResponse['data']['device_id'];
    }
}
```

Are there any pros and cons to each approach other than personal preferences of how long files one wants to have?

Comment: *Might* be a better fit on code review (but check their help pages on topicality first). Not sure it's a good fit for SO.